# Transform projection from EPSG:4326 into EPSG:900913

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, geojson, geodjango

.

i've got this problem about projection. .i just wanted to know what am i missing. .

i already displayed map base layer using openlayers through

```
base_layer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
           "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'} );
```

i also displayed my vector layer through

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Butuan");
    map.addLayer(layer);
    var format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
    var feat = format.read({{my_geojson|safe}});
    layer.addFeatures(feat);
```

and my position is

```
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(125.54915811889646, 8.90855351100384),11);
```

which positions the view as i desired it to be.
when i tried to change my base layer to

```
base_layer =  new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");
```

the center of the map is redirected to another location. .i guess that this problem pertains to the projection. i tried to change the center into

```
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(125.54915811889646, 8.90855351100384),11).transform(geographic, mercator);
```

which is defined as

```
var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
       var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
```

no changes has been noticed. .the position of the center is still redirected to another location. .

Can anyone suggest solutions on how to solve this problem?

I am using django framework. . vectorformats and simplejson to convert the retrieved spatial data into geojson from postgis. .

Comment: somebody has also helped me in dislaying my vector layer before i had noticed that problem. . credit to @jcs for helping. .

Comment: What is the projection of the map object?

Comment: it's SRID:32651. . by the way, can i add polygon to the database with the same projection?

Comment: When working with tiled layers like osm, google, bing, it is good idea to keep the map in 900913 projection as those tiles are in that system. otherwise many issues occur and it is difficult ro find problem.

Answer (score 1):

The correct call of the map center should be:

```
           var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
```

At least this is how it works for me.

If your vector data is not in EPSG:4326, you have to reproject that too. The tiles are in EPSG:900913, and you should not change that.

Comment: hi Andre.. tnx for suggesting solutions. . i think my my problem is reprojecting my data .. we'll i might worked it out. . ^_^